# Errorlevel in Powershell not reflect the action taken

Tags: powershell

I use below powershell script to install Chrome silently. However the error message displayed does not reflect the truth after it installed Chrome successfully. It showed the error message "Error found, Change to Manual Installation" and copied the installation file to destination instead of "Chrome Installed". Please review what went wrong with my script. Thanks.

```
$uri = "https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/latest/chrome_installer.exe"
$Path = $env:TEMP; $Installer = "chrome_installer.exe"; Invoke-WebRequest $uri -OutFile 
$Path$Installer; Start-Process -FilePath $Path$Installer -Args "/silent /install" -Verb RunAs 
-Wait; Remove-Item $Path$Installer
if( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 ) {
    Write-Output "Chrome Installed"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
} else {
Write-Output "Error found, Change to Manual Installation"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    Copy-Item -Path "${PSScriptRoot}\Software\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe" - 
    Destination "$($env:USERPROFILE)\downloads"
    Start $env:userprofile\downloads
}
exit
```

Comment: When you run it through PowerShell ISE what line does it fail on?

Comment: I doubt a non-elevated process could get the exit code of an elevated process – not that I tried.

Comment: I ran as administrator already. There was no error but the lastexitcode did not turn as 0.  The result was Chrome installed and also the file is copied to the downloads folder !

Comment: Check what the errorcode is and refer to the chrome install manual to what it actually means. It probably is succesfull with warning or something. or maybe it just has more than one succesful errorcodes. Eg: 1, succesfull, installed as single user. 2, succesfull, installed multi user. etc...

Comment: Also, it is possible that the errorcode is altered by the remove-item command. So the installer does return 0, but then the remove-item overwritten it with 5 or something.

Comment: Use `Start-Transcript <file path>.log` and check that log file afterwards to see what it indicates the result is. If you continue to have issues but it indicates the true outcome, maybe `Get-Content` and then `-Match` something with what it finds to indicate failure or success. Also move the `Remove-Item $Path$Installer -Force` to be within the applicable IF condition when it should be removed. I'd also ensure each line ends with a semicolon inside and outside the IF statements so if there are two blocks of code on one line, end BOTH with a semicolon just in case and as a best practice.

Comment: I found that I can only use   if ($?) and if (!$?)  in  order to have  the correct error message shown.  Even though I apply a simple copy-item with  $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0, it showed failed output but copy job was completed.  Transcript log also shown TRUE. It is weird !                                                                                                Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\vb88\downloads\Test_Copy0.log
PS>$global:?
True

Comment: Try doing this using [Try/catch[(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2), to determine if that grants you the control and consistently you are after.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment. Kind of something like this...
(of course, you'd not need all of this. I just made it noisy to see stuff)

```
# Chrome Silent installation

$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

Clear-Host
Try
{
    $uri  = 'https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/latest/chrome_installer.exe'
    $Path = $env:TEMP

    $Installer = 'chrome_installer.exe'
    Invoke-WebRequest $uri -OutFile $Path$Installer

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path$Installer

    Start-Process -FilePath $Path$Installer -Args "/silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait
    Write-Host 'Chrome Installed' -ForegroundColor Green

    Remove-Item -Path $Path$Installer -WhatIf
    Remove-Item -Path $Path$Installer -Verbose

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path$Installer
}
Catch 
{
    Write-Error -Message 'Error found, Change to Manual Installation'
    $PSItem[0].Exception.Message
    $Error.Clear()
}

$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

# Results
<#
VERBOSE: GET https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/latest/chrome_installer.exe with 0-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 1427176-byte response of content type application/octet-stream


    Directory: C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Local


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                      
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                      
-a----         8/29/2022  12:20 PM        1427176 Tempchrome_installer.exe                                                                                  
Chrome Installed
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Local\Tempchrome_installer.exe".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Local\Tempchrome_installer.exe".
...
#>


# Chrome Silent installation

$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

Clear-Host
Try
{
    $uri  = 'https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/latest/NOT_chrome_installer.exe'
    $Path = $env:TEMP

    $Installer = 'chrome_installer.exe'
    Invoke-WebRequest $uri -OutFile $Path$Installer

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path$Installer

    Start-Process -FilePath $Path$Installer -Args "/silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait
    Write-Host 'Chrome Installed' -ForegroundColor Green

    Remove-Item -Path $Path$Installer -WhatIf
    Remove-Item -Path $Path$Installer -Verbose

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path$Installer
}
Catch 
{
    Write-Error -Message 'Error found, Change to Manual Installation'
    $PSItem[0].Exception.Message
    $Error.Clear()
}

$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

# Results
<#
VERBOSE: GET https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/latest/NOT_chrome_installer.exe with 0-byte payload
...
 
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
#>
```

Comment: Of course,. the Try/Catch, good idea! I would simplify it even further and wrap the `Start-Process` in it, and for the `Catch` block just make it false but same that as the variable. Then you save just the result of the install of the chrome app and reference it post the other commands in that execution block. So `$ecode = Try{Start-Process -FilePath $Path$Installer -Args "/silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait;}Catch{$false;};`, run the rest of the job, then reference the result of that try catch block e.g. `If (!$ecode){"Error Occurred"; Exit;};` to take action if it was a false set with catch.

Comment: I did that code block just ot stick with the OP submission. Yet, agree with the simplification. I personally generally default to try/catch for anything where I require more controlled trapping and the like. Well, I still use If/then on the regular for other stuff. Yet, I am also a fan of switch blocks as well over if/then as well. we all have our preferences, for whatever reason. ;-}